# Cordova/PhoneGap: Double tap problems on iPad

Tags: cordova, ipad, phonegap-build

I've build a hybrid app (game) and I'm building my packages using PhoneGap Build. So far I've tested the app on an Android phone, and iPhone and an iPad. The iPad is the only device giving me problems which I suspect is related to double tapping and the 300ms delay.

First of all, I'm not experiencing the delay (my game uses the touchend event). But whenever I tap the screen, about half a second later (I'm guessing 300ms later ;) ) the entire game pauses for a tenth of a second or so. I think this must be related to double tapping because if I double tap, the pause does not occur.

So is there a way to disable double tapping altogether? Or any other way to get rid of the pause? As a side not, on the iPhone I'm not experiencing this problem, only on the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it indeed was related to the 300ms tap delay. Even though I'm actually using the touchend event to detect screen taps, en even though I **thought** I had disabled double clicks/taps with:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

and

```
<style>
  * {
    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Prevent Double tap (COPY/SELECT) on iOS */
  }
</style>
```

the 300ms delay was still there, so after 300ms a click event was generated which for some obscure reason was causing the pauses. So in order to prevent that, I simply "disabled" the **touchstart** event:

```
element.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

Voila. Problem solved. :)